# Why is there two extra column in the UserRoles in Asp.net Core Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identity

According to [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Custom User

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Custom Role:

```
public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{
    AppRole() { }
    public AppRole(string name) : base(name)
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppRoleClaim> RoleClaims { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string,
    IdentityUserClaim<string>, AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
    IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

But there are four columns in the table of AspNetUserRoles! (RoleId, UserId, RoleId1, UserId1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue relates that you didn't specify the foreign key when configure the one-to-many relationship, try to use the following code to specify the foreign key:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<
        ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string,
        IdentityUserClaim<string>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,
        IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
        { 
            // Each User can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.User)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(b =>
        {
            // Each Role can have many entries in the UserRole join table
            b.HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(e => e.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

    }
}
```

More detail information, see [Add User and Role navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-user-and-role-navigation-properties).

Answer (score -1):

the two extra columns(userid1 and roleid 1) are due to this line of code. actually icollection create an index on table in your DB. remove this and run migration hopefully extra columns will be gone

remove this `public virtual ICollection<AppUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }` from appuser and approle class